# Which method is better to get the number of an entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to get the number of products. I have two entities, the first SubCatgory and the second is Product.
So I have two ways to get product count. the first:

```
var subcatgory = await _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
int productCount = await _context.Products.CountAsync(p => p.SubCatgoryId == id);
```

the second:

```
var subcatgory = await _context.SubCategories.Include(s => s.Products).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
int productCount = subcatgory.Products.Count();
```

Which one is better in terms of performance? Why?
tip: I need subcatgory too.

**Thank you for your answer**

Comment: What do you mean by "I need subcategory too" when you want to count the number of products?

Comment: Did you try making a performance test? If performance really matters, that should be your first step. Also, the first line in your first snippet is not used for anything.

Comment: I need to use subcatgory on my page.  I mean I have to give subcatgory and productCount together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query. It returns data in one roundtrip to database.

```cs
var result = await _context.SubCategories
    .Where(m => m.Id == id)
    .Select(sc => new 
     {
        Subcategory = sc,
        ProductCount = sc.Products.Count()
     })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```